# saving session data when browser closes

Tags: php, session, session-state

I would like to know what the best way to save a shopping cart is. I'd like the shopping cart details (which are session variables) to persist even when the user closes his browser. I would consider saving the data in a table as soon as the window close event is fired but i'm not sure that jquery unLoad or beforeUnload events are what i need as they don't seem to work across different browers.

I'd appreciate any pointers to set me on the right path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much when a browser closes as keeping the session cookie in the browser.  If I understand correctly, you're using sessions (i.e. the $_SESSION variable), so it should be relatively easy.  PHP's function [session_set_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) would most likely be the way to go; there's also the option `session.cookie_lifetime` (found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)) that explains the session's cookie lifetime a bit more, even if you can't set it yourself.

The session cookie's lifetime is in seconds; so if you set it to 60 seconds and visit the site, the session cookie will only last 60 seconds before discarding the cookie, effectively destroying the session.  Set the lifetime to a high number in order to prevent this.

Comment: Funny, I've used sessions a lot and never knew that you could make them persist after closing the browser window. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @IQ_HiGh I had assumed from your question you were using [php sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).  Oops!

Comment: wow...that worked quite well. Thank you very much, you just saved me from what could have been a rather frustrating start of the week

Comment: @IQ_HiGh No problem, I'm glad to have helped!

Comment: @drderp i must have slightly misunderstood your response but i've sorted it out now. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you really didn't need any "on browser close" events or any crap like that. That's what I thought.

Comment: @ButtleButkus, no, everything I said can be handled completely on the server's side.

Comment: @drderp So I'd like to point out that the OP's question was inherently misguided. Other posters who tried to answer his question without questioning why he was asking it would have just led him further down the wrong path. You did a good job showing him the right path, the simplest path.

Answer (score 1):

Since the session data is server-side, and all the browser has is a session ID, all you need to do is make the session ID last longer.

This is done by editing the `php.ini` settings, particularly those regarding the lifetime of the session cookie. If it's `0`, then the cookie is cleared when the browser closes.

Try setting it to a high number. That will make the session persist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe save data when they are changing and not when the browser is closing. Saving could be in Database, Local Storage or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep your shopping cart data persisted anyway. If you want it when they're on the site and you still require it when they've left, just persist it. It's tricky to reliably pick up when a session is abandoned as they could close the machine down or kill the browser process. Every change to the cart should be saved until they explicitly kill their cart or the cookie associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You just save the data as soon as the data change is made. Why wait? As soon as someone adds an item to their cart, save it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery unLoad method works everywhere. I assume you want to store the cart in DB, when you talk about table(s). So you have to make synchronous ajax call to your server, so PHP could store it and probably return an identifier, which you should put into an cookie.

Problem is that this procedure can take relatively long time (1-2s). I'd just provide a Save button.

Comment: Why mess with any of this complexity? Why not just save it as soon as the user clicks "add to cart"?

Comment: Because user can make changes, when browsing his cart?

Comment: Ok, then you save the changes when they make those changes. Again, why worry about the browser close event at all?

Comment: Well, both ways could work. I don't see any big complexity in it. The saving function can be like 15 rows of Javascript using jQuery? And you save it once, so server load would be way lower. Plus i was answering this question "when browser closes", as the title says

Comment: When the user clicks to the change the contents of their cart, you are already sending a request to the server to do that. If you then wait until later to actually write changes to the DB, you are opening yourself up to unnecessary errors. I don't see how using a separate jQuery request later on is equivalent. It seems much worse.